# Importing Users into new WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I am migrating an existing site to WordPress. the existing site has a membership of over 6000 and their passwords were encrypted using sha1 and saved to the database. How can I import them into WordPress keeping their same password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this plugin
First Export
[Export Users to CSV](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/export-users-to-csv/)

Then Import

[Import Users from CSV](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-users-from-csv/)

You can also do this by exporting mysql wp_users & wp_usersmeta table.

Also [importing and exporting can be done with this single plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/)

Comment: I think this is the wrong direction. I am moving to WP. Therefore, I don't have any users to export from WP. I have users with passwords stored with md5('password') and I need to import them into a WP site while maintaining their password. I have no idea what there passwords are because they are stored encrypted.

Comment: jgravois is correct that this answer does not answer his/her question, since they are migrating from a different CMS to wordpress. However, for WP to WP user migration, copying over the wp_users & wp_usersmeta tables using a tool like phpmyadmin works great.

Answer (score 3):

For importing users to a new WordPress website, the best and easiest way to do it is by using a plugin. For that, first, you need to prepare a CSV file that contains all the users and the user data.

The plugin [WordPress Users and WooCommerce Customers Import Export Plugin](https://www.webtoffee.com/product/wordpress-users-woocommerce-customers-import-export/) will help you import the users into a WordPress site without much effort, taking the CSV as input.

**You can migrate the password also, so that after import also users can use their old password in the new site.**

If you are importing from a different platform or CMS, you will need to map the column headers of the CSV with the user data fields in WordPress. This will ensure that the data are correctly imported. After the mapping, all the data will be correctly imported to the website.

Also, using the plugin you can also be used to export the user data into a CSV file from a WordPress website.